# C# UWP: How to wire Prism to Secondary Window due to Threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, prism

So, basically, one of my feature ideas would need a secondary window (if you open Windows Mail and then click on "Open in a new Window, you can see what I mean).

For that you have two choices: ProjectionView (which is intended for non-interactive displays) and a completely new View. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views) by Microsoft states that this is the only way to do this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondaryPage), null);   
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();

        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
}
```

This works just fine. However, a problem arises when I then try to wire Prism/Unity into this new Window/Frame - since the new Window lives in its own thread, it will run into an exception if I simply try to let Prism autowire things (cross-thread data access violation).

Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed? Especially since the data to display comes from an SQLite store and, IIRC, SQLite isn't exactly thread-safe either.

edit: Callstack follows below:

```
Eine Schnittstelle, die für einen anderen Thread marshalled war, 
wurde von der Anwendung aufgerufen. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

at Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
at Prism.Windows.Navigation.FrameFacadeAdapter.GetValue(DependencyProperty dependencyProperty)
at Prism.Windows.AppModel.SessionStateService.GetSessionStateForFrame(IFrameFacade frame)
at Prism.Windows.PrismApplication.<>c__DisplayClass54_0.<InitializeFrameAsync>b__0(IFrameFacade frame)
at Prism.Windows.Mvvm.SessionStateAwarePage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs navigationEventArgs)
```

Comment: Did you use the following nuget package?https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Unity/

Comment: Yes. This is a working UWP application with Prism/Unity which I now want to add an additional feature to. One which requires a second window.
The second window works if I _do not_ change the base class of the page to the one Prism is using.

Comment: Can you please include more details about the exception/callstack? This should tell us who is trying to access what from the wrong thread. Thanks!

Comment: added the requested stack trace